# For what x is the linearization of the function accurate to within 0.5 of the true value?

Tags: calculus

I'm having difficulty with this linearization problem and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

For what $x \in R$ is the linearization of $\sqrt{4-x}$ accurate to within $0.5$ of the true value?

Here's what I've done so far:

Linearization of $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x}$ at $x=0$:
$$L(x) = 2-\frac{1}{4}x$$ 
$$|f(x)-L(x)|<0.5$$
$$|\sqrt{4-x}-(2-\frac{1}{4}x)|< 0.5 $$
$$L(x)-0.5<f(x)<L(x)+0.5$$
$$(2-\frac{1}{4}x)-0.5<\sqrt{4-x}<(2-\frac{1}{4}x)+0.5$$
$$f(x)=L(x)-0.5$$
$$\sqrt{4-x}=2-\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}$$
I  then proceeded to solve for $x$ and ended up with $-28.966<x<0.9666$

However, the answer is $-7.6569<x<3.6569$

Where did I go wrong and how can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what is mean by linearization, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the graph of $f(x)$ is concave down, we know that $L(x)-f(x)$ is positive.  You just have to solve $L(x)-f(x) = 0.5.$

$$2-\frac{x}{4}-\sqrt{4-x}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$8-x=2+4\sqrt{4-x}$$

$$(6-x)^2 = (4\sqrt{4-x})^2$$

$$x^2-12x+36 =16(4-x)$$

$$x^2 +4x-28 = 0$$

$$x=-2\pm 4\sqrt{2}$$